# Pasting data into a WPF Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to paste data from the clipboard into the bottom a WPF Datagrid using the code below but it keeps saying that index is either negative or above rows count.

CanUSerAddRows is set to true

```
string text = Clipboard.GetText();

string[] line = Regex.Split(text , ",");

foreach (string word in line)
{

   int index = DgInvoiceLines.Items.Count;
   string prodCode = word ;

   DataGridCell ProdCodeCell = GetCell(index, 0);
   DataGridCellInfo pcell = new DataGridCellInfo(ProdCodeCell);
   string ProdCellContentType = pcell.Column.GetCellContent(pcell.Item).GetType().Name.ToString();
   if (ProdCellContentType == "TextBlock") ((TextBlock)cell.Column.GetCellContent(cell.Item)).Text = prodCode;
   else if (ProdCellContentType == "TextBox") ((TextBox)cell.Column.GetCellContent(cell.Item)).Text = prodCode;

   DataGridCell CommentCodeCell = GetCell(index, 12);
   DataGridCellInfo Ccell = new DataGridCellInfo(CommentCodeCell);
   string CommentCellContentType = Ccell.Column.GetCellContent(Ccell.Item).GetType().Name.ToString();
   if (CommentCellContentType == "TextBlock") ((TextBlock)cell.Column.GetCellContent(cell.Item)).Text = "Ord";
   else if (CommentCellContentType == "TextBox") ((TextBox)cell.Column.GetCellContent(cell.Item)).Text = "Ord";

   index = index + 1;
}
```

**EDIT**

If I change the index to 0 it throws a null reference exception

Any help is hugely appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach in my opinion is to create additional data objects to add to the underlying collection that your grid is (I assume) bound to.
If the grids ItemsSource is an `ObservableCollection<T>` then the new rows will appear automatically